# Can I convert a Stream object to a FileInfo object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For the [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) constructor you need a FileInfo object. I rather use some kind of stream object(f.i. MemoryStream), because I don't need to save the file to the server itself, but expose it as a FileStream anyway to the user. I don't want to make files which I have to delete lateron from servers which are only there for generating purposes and never used again. Apart from that, otherwise I need also the necessary rights for the application/user on the directory/file on the server.

So my question is then: How can I convert a stream object to a FileInfo object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following constructor to ExcelPackage makes it possible to use Streams instead.

```
public ExcelPackage( Stream stream ) {
    _package = Package.Open( stream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite );

    Uri uriDefaultContentType = new Uri( "/default.xml", UriKind.Relative );
    PackagePart partTemp = _package.CreatePart( uriDefaultContentType, "application/xml" );

    XmlDocument workbook = Workbook.WorkbookXml; 

    _package.CreateRelationship( Workbook.WorkbookUri, TargetMode.Internal, schemaRelationships + "/officeDocument" );

    _package.DeletePart( uriDefaultContentType );
}
```

Comment: Where and how can I change the source code like you did?

Answer (score 10):

You can't convert the `Stream` as such to a `FileInfo`; they represent entirely different things. A `Stream` contains data thay may or may not represent a file on disk. A `FileInfo` on the other hand contains metadata about a file, that may or may not exist.

What you *can* do is to write the contents of the `Stream` to a file on disk, create a `FileInfo` pointing at that file and pass that `FileInfo` to the constructor.

Comment: He explicitly said that he doesn't want to do that.

Comment: @SLaks: I know. And I informed him why his wish is unlikely to come true. However, your suggestion with adding a constructor in the code is a good one.

Comment: I was trying to avoid to have to change the source code, but that may become unavoidable then.

Comment: @Michael: yes it seems to stand between those two; fix the code or save the file. Either one will save the day.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can

```
var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
excelPackage.Load(fileStream);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `FileInfo` class is a simple wrapper around a path to a file on disk.
It is not possible to have a `FileInfo` wrap a memory stream.

However, you can download the source code and add a constructor that takes a `Stream`.  (The file path is only used in the `WriteDebugFile` method)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that , what you should be doing is outputting the memory stream to file and getting the FileInfo object for the newly created file and passing it to the ExcelPackage.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for `ExcelPackage`, it uses the `Package.Open` method on the `FullName` property of the `FileInfo` object passed to the constructor, with `FileMode.Open` and `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, to initialize a `Package` object.

The `Package.Open` method can also accept a `Stream` directly.

If you wanted, you could overload the `ExcelPackage` constructor yourself to accept a `Stream` parameter, and simply call `Package.Open` on that `Stream` object--which could easily be, for example, a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score -3):

As mentioned by `Fredrik Mörk`, this is not possible as their is no default conversion available between both types and is not a recommended as well.

Just for `reference`,  You can though provide your own `Conversion` logic by implementing [**`IConvertible`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) Interface. again not right approach in this scenario, but may be helpful somewhere else.

```
class CustomStream : Stream, IConvertible
    {
        public FileInfo ConvertToFileInfo()
        {
            return new FileInfo("");
        }
    }
```

This is how you convert It

```
 CustomStream stream = new CustomStream();
 FileInfo fileInfo = stream.ConvertToFileInfo();
```

Comment: But whats the use... You can also create an empty FileInfo and give it to the function instead of making an extension. Probably the ExcelPackage uses the FileInfo to get values. Faking can give unpredictable results

Comment: This will not work.  `ExcelPackage` will try to read the file from the path in the `FileInfo`.